# how can I search for multiple items by FIND_IN_SET?

Tags: php

I have a user_privilege column in database as the following :

```
username        user_privilege 

a                  7gz,agt_courses,newbill

b                 dataDisplay,previllige,newUsers

c                 newbill,dataDisplay,previllige
```

I want to search for every value in user_privilege column I used `OR` between every `FIND_IN_SET` but doesn't work right what I do?

I write the php code:

```
ob_start();
session_start();        

    $username = $_POST['username'];
            $username2 = $_POST['username2'];
    $finduser = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM LOGIN 
        WHERE username='".$username."' AND username2='".$username2."' 
        AND FIND_IN_SET('7gz', user_previllige) OR FIND_IN_SET('agt_courses',user_previllige) OR FIND_IN_SET('newbill',user_previllige) OR FIND_IN_SET('new_Trainee',user_previllige)OR FIND_IN_SET('dataDisplay',user_previllige) OR FIND_IN_SET ('previllige',user_previllige) OR FIND_IN_SET('newUsers',user_previllige) OR FIND_IN_SET('Customers ',user_previllige )") 
        or die("error");

if(mysqli_num_rows($finduser) !=0)
        {

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finduser))
                {$uname = $row['username'];
                $uname2 = $row['username2'];
                $arr=explode(",",$row['user_previllige']);
                //if($arr=='dataDisplay'){echo 'yes';}//elseif($arr=='new_Trainee'){echo 'yes';}
                }

        }

        if($username == $uname && $username2 == $uname2)
            {$_SESSION['sessionname'] =$uname;
            $_SESSION['sessionname2'] =$uname2;
            $_SESSION['sessionpre'] =$arr;
            header ("location:../agtSite/agt2 - Copy.php");
            //echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" url="../agtSite/agt2 - Copy.php"/>';
            }

            else echo 'اسم المستخدم غير موجود <a href="login.php"> اذهب للتسجيل مره اخري </a> ';

}
ob_end_flush();
```

BUT it doesn't work right 
Is there  any solution for multiple search ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this query :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    LOGIN
WHERE
    username = 'a'
    AND 
    (
            FIND_IN_SET( '7gz' ,user_privilege )
        OR  FIND_IN_SET( 'agt_courses' ,user_privilege )
        OR  FIND_IN_SET( 'newbill' ,user_privilege )
        OR  FIND_IN_SET( 'new_Trainee' ,user_privilege )
        OR  FIND_IN_SET( 'dataDisplay' ,user_privilege )
        OR  FIND_IN_SET( 'previllige' ,user_privilege )
        OR  FIND_IN_SET( 'newUsers' ,user_privilege )
        OR  FIND_IN_SET( 'Customers' ,user_privilege )
    )
```

Tested with the below test table and test data . It worked :

```
--
-- Table structure for table `login`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_privilege` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `login`
--

INSERT INTO `login` (`id`, `username`, `user_privilege`) VALUES
(1, 'a', '7gz,agt_courses,newbill'),
(2, 'b', 'dataDisplay,previllige,newUsers'),
(3, 'c', 'newbill,dataDisplay,previllige');
```

Comment: @user2890838 Cool , no problem . You might want to select my answer as chosen . Cheers , ...

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your script. Column name is `user_privilege` and you have used `user_previllige` in your query.

Use

```
$finduser = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM LOGIN 
        WHERE username='".$username."' AND username2='".$username2."' 
        AND FIND_IN_SET('7gz', user_privilege) OR FIND_IN_SET('agt_courses',user_privilege) OR FIND_IN_SET('newbill',user_privilege) OR FIND_IN_SET('new_Trainee',user_privilege)OR FIND_IN_SET('dataDisplay',user_privilege) OR FIND_IN_SET ('previllige',user_privilege) OR FIND_IN_SET('newUsers',user_privilege) OR FIND_IN_SET('Customers ',user_privilege)") 
        or die("error");
```

Comment: OK but that I wrote right in my file . the problem there in reading OR wrong ,that some users go to agt page .which is the right reading is all users enter the agt page

Comment: There is a typo in the above file. Are you refering to the same file or some other file?

Comment: ok I edit it but not this is problem .the problem there in reading OR wrong ,that some users go to agt page .which is the right reading is all users enter the agt page